# WKWebview - Intercepting JS CSS

Tags: javascript, css, ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

My application uses UIwebview to intercept all the js/css/image file and load from local relative path using NSURLProtocol.

Since Apple force to use WKWebview from Jan 2021. I was forced to use WKwebview, but i'm facing problem in intercepting javascript & css files. Using custom protocol i can able to intercept image files.

Is there any way to intercept js/css files from relative path, any suggessions?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/371612143/WQAWKWebview  this sdk has a solution。which use ajaxhook to send post message and use NSURLProtocol to offline cache html/JS/CSS resource